# Using onRelease with sIFR

Tags: javascript, jquery, sifr

How do I catch onclick events in sIFR? I know I'm meant to use  `onRelease`, but can't figure out *how*. I've been looking high and low for a solution to use it in combination with jQuery ui tabs, which is triggered with this function:

```
$(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

I've tried simply inserting it like this, obviously without any luck:

```
sIFR.replace(AkzidGroLight, {
  selector:  '#tabsNav h4.Berthold-light',
  onRelease: function(fi) { $('#tabs').tabs(); },
  css: [ 
    'a {text-align: center; display: block; text-decoration: none; letter-spacing: -0.5;}',
    'a:link { color: #333333; }' ,
    'a:hover { color: #999999; }' 
  ],
  offsetTop:   5,
  tuneHeight:  5,
  wmode: 'transparent'
});
```

Comment: That looks fine actually. Could you be more specific? This is with r436?

Comment: Yes, this is with r436. It might be something else that is blocking it, although I'm not getting any errors in Firebug. I'll upload it to a server today for better viewing. And thank you for the work you're doing!

Comment: Here's a demo of the page http://bit.ly/pkhzv  The links in question are the 'Contributors' and 'Most read posts' tabs in the right-hand column.

Answer (score 0):

wmode transparent is buggy buggy buggy. Start by removing that and see if the behavior changes. Just in case your callback has a problem, put an alert or console.log in there to make sure it's actually getting called.